# Replace missing values filtering group of rows with mode value of group in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to Python and wanted to understand how to work on Missing values in Python.
 Piece of extracted Data is as below:

```
City    X   Y   Z
CityA   1   NaN 3 
CityA   1   3   4  
CityA   4   6   NaN
CityB   3   4   5 
CityB   6   NaN NaN  
CityB   NaN 6   4
CityC   1   NaN 3 
CityC   1   3   4  
CityC   NaN 6   NaN
```

I know how to replace missing values, but not sure how to replace mode value of a group from a Dataframe. Presently what I am doing is,

- Create a new Dataframe `df1 = df[df["City"]=="City A"]`
- Replace all missing values with mode values using below code
  `for column in df1.columns:
  df1[column].fillna(df1[column].mode()[0], inplace=True)`
- Repeat the same for all City groups (City A, City B, City C) rows. Later once done, I will merge the data.

I am 100% sure I am doing things wrong and need help to understand the best method to work on similar problems.

Comment: can you please post the data as text? Images cannot be copied thus we cant test. For more reference , please check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @anky_91 Added the data in code format. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: do you need `df.groupby('City')['X','Y','Z'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iloc[0]))` ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean by mode value? I looked into what it does and it groups the columns values from smallest to highest. Having seen in your code example that you take the first value from this group, I conclude that you just want to fill the NaNs with lowest values in that column. For this you can use this code:

`for col in df:
    df[col].fillna(df[col].min(), inplace=True)`